# Reshape array into data frame using iterations

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I have an array of 300 samples - the "column" in the name of the array data loops every 100 iterations - e.g., `"mu[100,1]"` and `"mu[1,2]"` are next to each other - please find reproducible sample data below:

```
x = structure(c(56024.580718517, -71759.7965304655, -19346.1677826161, 
143217.329907636, -6608.04518760051, 30785.2441469217, -21694.9506114719, 
138874.632429514, -95542.6004176402, 167668.653191049, 132961.914733722, 
-23770.4512687057, -33596.5026292299, 206196.416630238, 20634.7942723285, 
42593.2988110867, 2819.1502820382, 298583.717025781, 99754.0884869142, 
262717.339976129, 108226.003916101, 39921.7288427061, -46644.5089385037, 
26502.3674167487, 29727.8742872285, 31301.2319036174, 47124.6857952452, 
96300.496886525, 147465.658307984, 53359.6125199006, 335765.603984829, 
48328.6759131276, -50212.6803952706, -52161.4144776515, 22013.8850034851, 
-75943.5024012008, -5472.51311196868, 5074.25527371626, 90569.6632533503, 
-116279.054905015, 57669.5918399219, 495532.019038654, 14016.668608461, 
-36098.9536033779, -41254.1515520381, 65562.8546018512, 318918.341056716, 
64847.6323903132, 93375.7462147732, -66823.6107564668, 65999.0343997755, 
38684.4034462648, -10297.2131034494, 14881.1770174947, 199584.236643199, 
-25395.2682878221, -24896.9032153378, -69717.79697306, -73560.8787097404, 
82306.4361099676, 64481.0468971623, -106422.825465266, 162242.284307183, 
40636.1617487436, -176515.25549769, 119186.267913034, 38997.0709509129, 
171998.402672072, 527434.61052007, 48565.9147663558, 89736.8086732599, 
69974.9663840344, -82400.4258771297, 23285.9528089444, 24037.1902429704, 
-78302.6316905592, -839.61808263478, 119604.770835114, -120885.638568511, 
303386.671654727, 563928.836090433, -12837.3458214897, 14932.4960155109, 
108496.453162252, 96424.4175620037, 241431.881512062, 211285.816118368, 
59151.4036009351, 789906.666649959, 65766.6517864702, 121398.724820442, 
-125743.415110351, 91173.9897386867, -12035.526460063, -79099.9983749241, 
58299.5775481516, -35377.1922969648, -10108.5617417662, -40651.4245562909, 
48275.8184079196, 56024.580718517, -71759.7965304655, -19346.1677826161, 
143217.329907636, -6608.04518760051, 31947.6467669724, -21694.9506114719, 
138874.632429514, -95542.6004176402, 168831.0558111, 132961.914733722, 
-23770.4512687057, -33596.5026292299, 207358.819250288, 20634.7942723285, 
42593.2988110867, 2819.1502820382, 299746.119645831, 99754.0884869142, 
256905.326875876, 107063.60129605, 39921.7288427061, -46644.5089385037, 
26502.3674167487, 29727.8742872285, 31301.2319036174, 47124.6857952452, 
96300.496886525, 147465.658307984, 52658.8231244761, 335765.603984829, 
48328.6759131276, -50212.6803952706, -53323.8170977022, 22013.8850034851, 
-75943.5024012008, -5472.51311196868, 5074.25527371626, 90569.6632533503, 
-115116.652284964, 58831.9944599726, 492044.811178502, 14016.668608461, 
-37261.3562234286, -40091.7489319874, 65562.8546018512, 317755.938436666, 
64847.6323903132, 93375.7462147732, -66823.6107564668, 65999.0343997755, 
38684.4034462648, -11459.6157235001, 14881.1770174947, 201909.041883301, 
-24694.4788923976, -24896.9032153378, -69717.79697306, -73560.8787097404, 
81144.0334899169, 64481.0468971623, -106422.825465266, 162242.284307183, 
40636.1617487436, -176515.25549769, 119186.267913034, 38997.0709509129, 
169673.597431971, 530921.818380222, 48565.9147663558, 90899.2112933106, 
68812.5637639838, -82400.4258771297, 22123.5501888937, 24037.1902429704, 
-75977.8264504579, -839.61808263478, 119604.770835114, -120885.638568511, 
303386.671654727, 579501.683375718, -12837.3458214897, 14932.4960155109, 
108496.453162252, 98749.2228021051, 247243.894612315, 211285.816118368, 
59151.4036009351, 788744.264029908, 65766.6517864702, 121398.724820442, 
-125743.415110351, 91173.9897386867, -12035.526460063, -79099.9983749241, 
58299.5775481516, -35377.1922969648, -8946.15912171553, -40651.4245562909, 
48275.8184079196, 56024.580718517, -71759.7965304655, -19346.1677826161, 
143217.329907636, -6608.04518760051, 30785.2441469217, -21694.9506114719, 
138874.632429514, -95542.6004176402, 167668.653191049, 132961.914733722, 
-23770.4512687057, -33596.5026292299, 206196.416630238, 20634.7942723285, 
42593.2988110867, 2819.1502820382, 313694.951086439, 100916.491106965, 
251093.313775623, 108226.003916101, 39921.7288427061, -44319.7036984024, 
26502.3674167487, 29727.8742872285, 31301.2319036174, 47124.6857952452, 
96300.496886525, 147465.658307984, 53821.2257445268, 335765.603984829, 
48328.6759131276, -50212.6803952706, -53323.8170977022, 22013.8850034851, 
-72456.2945410488, -5472.51311196868, 5074.25527371626, 94056.8711135023, 
-116279.054905015, 58370.3812353464, 496694.421658705, 14016.668608461, 
-36098.9536033779, -38929.3463119367, 65562.8546018512, 317755.938436666, 
64847.6323903132, 93375.7462147732, -66823.6107564668, 65999.0343997755, 
38684.4034462648, -9134.81048339875, 14881.1770174947, 201909.041883301, 
-26096.0576832466, -24896.9032153378, -69717.79697306, -72398.4760896897, 
81144.0334899169, 64481.0468971623, -104098.020225165, 166891.894787386, 
40636.1617487436, -176515.25549769, 119186.267913034, 38997.0709509129, 
171998.402672072, 526272.207900019, 48565.9147663558, 93224.0165334119, 
69974.9663840344, -82400.4258771297, 23285.9528089444, 24037.1902429704, 
-78302.6316905592, -839.61808263478, 119604.770835114, -120885.638568511, 
303386.671654727, 579501.683375718, -12837.3458214897, 14932.4960155109, 
108496.453162252, 96424.4175620037, 241431.881512062, 211285.816118368, 
61476.2088410364, 791069.06927001, 65766.6517864702, 121398.724820442, 
-125743.415110351, 92336.3923587373, -12035.526460063, -79099.9983749241, 
58299.5775481516, -35377.1922969648, -10108.5617417662, -40651.4245562909, 
48275.8184079196), .Names = c("mu[1,1]", "mu[2,1]", "mu[3,1]", 
"mu[4,1]", "mu[5,1]", "mu[6,1]", "mu[7,1]", "mu[8,1]", "mu[9,1]", 
"mu[10,1]", "mu[11,1]", "mu[12,1]", "mu[13,1]", "mu[14,1]", "mu[15,1]", 
"mu[16,1]", "mu[17,1]", "mu[18,1]", "mu[19,1]", "mu[20,1]", "mu[21,1]", 
"mu[22,1]", "mu[23,1]", "mu[24,1]", "mu[25,1]", "mu[26,1]", "mu[27,1]", 
"mu[28,1]", "mu[29,1]", "mu[30,1]", "mu[31,1]", "mu[32,1]", "mu[33,1]", 
"mu[34,1]", "mu[35,1]", "mu[36,1]", "mu[37,1]", "mu[38,1]", "mu[39,1]", 
"mu[40,1]", "mu[41,1]", "mu[42,1]", "mu[43,1]", "mu[44,1]", "mu[45,1]", 
"mu[46,1]", "mu[47,1]", "mu[48,1]", "mu[49,1]", "mu[50,1]", "mu[51,1]", 
"mu[52,1]", "mu[53,1]", "mu[54,1]", "mu[55,1]", "mu[56,1]", "mu[57,1]", 
"mu[58,1]", "mu[59,1]", "mu[60,1]", "mu[61,1]", "mu[62,1]", "mu[63,1]", 
"mu[64,1]", "mu[65,1]", "mu[66,1]", "mu[67,1]", "mu[68,1]", "mu[69,1]", 
"mu[70,1]", "mu[71,1]", "mu[72,1]", "mu[73,1]", "mu[74,1]", "mu[75,1]", 
"mu[76,1]", "mu[77,1]", "mu[78,1]", "mu[79,1]", "mu[80,1]", "mu[81,1]", 
"mu[82,1]", "mu[83,1]", "mu[84,1]", "mu[85,1]", "mu[86,1]", "mu[87,1]", 
"mu[88,1]", "mu[89,1]", "mu[90,1]", "mu[91,1]", "mu[92,1]", "mu[93,1]", 
"mu[94,1]", "mu[95,1]", "mu[96,1]", "mu[97,1]", "mu[98,1]", "mu[99,1]", 
"mu[100,1]", "mu[1,2]", "mu[2,2]", "mu[3,2]", "mu[4,2]", "mu[5,2]", 
"mu[6,2]", "mu[7,2]", "mu[8,2]", "mu[9,2]", "mu[10,2]", "mu[11,2]", 
"mu[12,2]", "mu[13,2]", "mu[14,2]", "mu[15,2]", "mu[16,2]", "mu[17,2]", 
"mu[18,2]", "mu[19,2]", "mu[20,2]", "mu[21,2]", "mu[22,2]", "mu[23,2]", 
"mu[24,2]", "mu[25,2]", "mu[26,2]", "mu[27,2]", "mu[28,2]", "mu[29,2]", 
"mu[30,2]", "mu[31,2]", "mu[32,2]", "mu[33,2]", "mu[34,2]", "mu[35,2]", 
"mu[36,2]", "mu[37,2]", "mu[38,2]", "mu[39,2]", "mu[40,2]", "mu[41,2]", 
"mu[42,2]", "mu[43,2]", "mu[44,2]", "mu[45,2]", "mu[46,2]", "mu[47,2]", 
"mu[48,2]", "mu[49,2]", "mu[50,2]", "mu[51,2]", "mu[52,2]", "mu[53,2]", 
"mu[54,2]", "mu[55,2]", "mu[56,2]", "mu[57,2]", "mu[58,2]", "mu[59,2]", 
"mu[60,2]", "mu[61,2]", "mu[62,2]", "mu[63,2]", "mu[64,2]", "mu[65,2]", 
"mu[66,2]", "mu[67,2]", "mu[68,2]", "mu[69,2]", "mu[70,2]", "mu[71,2]", 
"mu[72,2]", "mu[73,2]", "mu[74,2]", "mu[75,2]", "mu[76,2]", "mu[77,2]", 
"mu[78,2]", "mu[79,2]", "mu[80,2]", "mu[81,2]", "mu[82,2]", "mu[83,2]", 
"mu[84,2]", "mu[85,2]", "mu[86,2]", "mu[87,2]", "mu[88,2]", "mu[89,2]", 
"mu[90,2]", "mu[91,2]", "mu[92,2]", "mu[93,2]", "mu[94,2]", "mu[95,2]", 
"mu[96,2]", "mu[97,2]", "mu[98,2]", "mu[99,2]", "mu[100,2]", 
"mu[1,3]", "mu[2,3]", "mu[3,3]", "mu[4,3]", "mu[5,3]", "mu[6,3]", 
"mu[7,3]", "mu[8,3]", "mu[9,3]", "mu[10,3]", "mu[11,3]", "mu[12,3]", 
"mu[13,3]", "mu[14,3]", "mu[15,3]", "mu[16,3]", "mu[17,3]", "mu[18,3]", 
"mu[19,3]", "mu[20,3]", "mu[21,3]", "mu[22,3]", "mu[23,3]", "mu[24,3]", 
"mu[25,3]", "mu[26,3]", "mu[27,3]", "mu[28,3]", "mu[29,3]", "mu[30,3]", 
"mu[31,3]", "mu[32,3]", "mu[33,3]", "mu[34,3]", "mu[35,3]", "mu[36,3]", 
"mu[37,3]", "mu[38,3]", "mu[39,3]", "mu[40,3]", "mu[41,3]", "mu[42,3]", 
"mu[43,3]", "mu[44,3]", "mu[45,3]", "mu[46,3]", "mu[47,3]", "mu[48,3]", 
"mu[49,3]", "mu[50,3]", "mu[51,3]", "mu[52,3]", "mu[53,3]", "mu[54,3]", 
"mu[55,3]", "mu[56,3]", "mu[57,3]", "mu[58,3]", "mu[59,3]", "mu[60,3]", 
"mu[61,3]", "mu[62,3]", "mu[63,3]", "mu[64,3]", "mu[65,3]", "mu[66,3]", 
"mu[67,3]", "mu[68,3]", "mu[69,3]", "mu[70,3]", "mu[71,3]", "mu[72,3]", 
"mu[73,3]", "mu[74,3]", "mu[75,3]", "mu[76,3]", "mu[77,3]", "mu[78,3]", 
"mu[79,3]", "mu[80,3]", "mu[81,3]", "mu[82,3]", "mu[83,3]", "mu[84,3]", 
"mu[85,3]", "mu[86,3]", "mu[87,3]", "mu[88,3]", "mu[89,3]", "mu[90,3]", 
"mu[91,3]", "mu[92,3]", "mu[93,3]", "mu[94,3]", "mu[95,3]", "mu[96,3]", 
"mu[97,3]", "mu[98,3]", "mu[99,3]", "mu[100,3]"))
```

How do I reshape this array so that each 100th iteration becomes a new column?
The final data frame would look something like this:

```
            mu[,1]     mu[,2]     mu[,3]
mu[1,]   56024.581  52658.823  53821.226
mu[2,]  -71759.797 335765.604 335765.604
mu[3,]  -19346.168  48328.676  48328.676
mu[4,]  143217.330 -50212.680 -50212.680
mu[5,]   -6608.045 -53323.817 -53323.817
mu[6,]   30785.244  22013.885  22013.885
mu[7,]  -21694.951 -75943.502 -72456.295
mu[8,]  138874.632  -5472.513  -5472.513
mu[9,]  -95542.600   5074.255   5074.255
mu[10,] 167668.653  90569.663  94056.871
.......  ........    .........  ........
mu[100,] 39013.452  17943.325  -4529.532
```

Comment: I'm almost certain `matrix(x, 100, 3)` is the solution. Are you sure `mu[1,2]` is `52658.832` not `56024.5807`?

Comment: Oh i see, its because the data is repeated - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @12b345b6b78, one simple way is `matrix(x, nrow = 100, ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE)`

```
             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
  [1,]   56024.5807   56024.5807   56024.5807
  [2,]  -71759.7965  -71759.7965  -71759.7965
  [3,]  -19346.1678  -19346.1678  -19346.1678
  [4,]  143217.3299  143217.3299  143217.3299
  [5,]   -6608.0452   -6608.0452   -6608.0452
  [6,]   30785.2441   31947.6468   30785.2441
  [7,]  -21694.9506  -21694.9506  -21694.9506
  [8,]  138874.6324  138874.6324  138874.6324
  [9,]  -95542.6004  -95542.6004  -95542.6004
 [10,]  167668.6532  168831.0558  167668.6532
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the fastest solution, but it also works if the order of the entries is not guaranteed because it extracts the coordinates from the name attribute.

```
library(tidyverse)

tidy <- tibble::tibble(value = x, name = names(x)) %>%
  tidyr::extract(name, into = c("r", "c"), regex = "mu\\[([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\\]") %>%
  dplyr::mutate_at(dplyr::vars(c, r), as.numeric) %>%
  tidyr::spread(c, value = value) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(r)
```

Comment: thanks for your help - seems I missed something very obvious